# How to make PowerBI redraw the chart based on a legend is selected

Tags: powerbi

I have a table in PowerBI as my data source.

Table
| Time | type | count | environment |

And I have 2 charts for that table.

- Line chart (x axis is Time, y axis is sum of count, legend is type)
- Stacked column chart (x axis is Time, y axis is sum of count, legend is environment)

My question is when I select 1 legend in the line chart, the Stacked column chart get redrawn. The values of the selected legend is drawn with normal colors but other values is still shown as 'faded' color.
i.e. something like this [image]

Can I make the stacked column chart to be redrawn so that the values only shown the legend which was selected in the line chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called **cross filtering**. If you want **full filtering** put the legend into a slicer next to the column chart und you'll get the desired effect.